# "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" while assigning viewcontrollers to tabbar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have written some code which works fine in simulator but its not working in Device. I have assigned 4 viewcontrollers to tabbar and the following is the code for HomeScreen, which is assigned as a first view controller in tabbar. It crashes on the first line of viewdidload().

when I remove everything from viewdidload() it works.

```
class HomeScreen: UIViewController {
    var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgLine:UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnActiveDeals:UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnActiveClaims:UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnNearByDeals:UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var horizontalSpaceConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var tblMain:UITableView!

    var mydeals : MyDealsViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        btnActiveDeals.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        btnActiveDeals.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        btnActiveDeals.autoresizesSubviews = true

        btnActiveClaims.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        btnActiveClaims.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        btnActiveClaims.autoresizesSubviews = true

        btnNearByDeals.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        btnNearByDeals.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        btnNearByDeals.autoresizesSubviews = true

        tblMain.backgroundView = nil
        tblMain.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    }
```

Please find below code for assigning the homescreen to tabbar.

```
 let centerViewController1 = HomeScreen(nibName: "HomeScreen", bundle: nil)
 let centerViewController2 = HomeScreen(nibName: "HomeScreen", bundle: nil)
 let centerViewController3 = HomeScreen(nibName: "HomeScreen", bundle: nil)
 let centerViewController4 = HomeScreen(nibName: "HomeScreen", bundle: nil)

 tabBarController = UITabBarController()
 var controllers = [centerViewController1,centerViewController2,centerViewController3,centerViewController4]
 tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers
 tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use breakpoints and see which line returns that error.

Comment: If you are using storyboard, why you are creating tabBarController = UITabBarController()?

Comment: @CeceXX the error is on first line of the viewdidload..
btnActiveDeals.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
This works fine in simulator and once I comment whole viewdidload then it goes further. is there any problem with allocation of the buttons and tableview??

Comment: Are you using storyboards or xib files to lay out the view controller UI? It’s crashing because the IBOutlet connections aren’t being set up by the time viewDidLoad is called, but that could be for a number of reasons. First question is to find out whether you’re using storyboard files (.storyboard) or xib files (.xib)

Answer (score 0):

It is failing because at viewDidLoad, btnActiveDeals is not yet initiated.

Reason: The way you are initialising your view controller.

Solution:

1- If you have created your viewcontroller in storyboard please instantiate it like below

```
 if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IdentifierDefinedInStoryboard") as? VC {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

2- If you have created your viewcontroller in xib, please instantiate it like below

```
let centerViewController1 = CenterViewController()
```

please tell me if it helps!